# counting values between two numbers haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to find out  values between two numbers. So far I have:

```
heightbetween :: Float -> Float -> [Float] -> Int
heightbetween _ _ [] = 0
heightbetween n s (x:xs)
 | (n < x) : (s > x) = 1 + (heightbetween n s xs)
 | otherwise = heightbetween n s xs
```

Comment: Use `&&` to "and" two booleans, not `:`. Also, `length . filter (\x -> n<x && x<s)` should do.

Comment: Yes I have it but did it this way:

Comment: {heightbetween :: Float -> Float -> [Float] -> Int
heightbetween _ _ [] = 0
heightbetween n s (x:xs) 
 | (n < x) && (s > x) = 1 + (heightbetween n s xs)
 | otherwise = heightbetween n s xs
} I did it this way, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you could filter the list of heights to the predicate of being between the upper and lower bound, and determine the length of the remaining list of elements:

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

the first argument allows you to see whether a predicate is true or not. For example:

```
filter ((==) 0) [1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 1, 4, 0, 6, 2, 0]
```

will result in the list

```
 [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Determining the length of this list will show you how many elements satisfy your predicate.